# Line(s) only printed once when returning to a menu

Tags: python

I'm making a quiz in which I have a text file from which saved scores and usernames have to be retrieved. However, as soon as I get the scores to return to the main menu only one of the results displays.

This is what my text file looks like:

```
Ted History Easy 4 points Grade : B
Ted Biology Hard 5 points Grade : A
John History Medium 3 points Grade : C
Ted History Medium 2 points Grade : D
```

This is my code :

```
def results():
   found = False
   username = input("Enter username :")
   for line in open("scorefile.txt","r"):
       if username in line:
           print (line)
           found = True
           return menu()
   if not found:
       print("No such user")
       return menu()
```

Because of the return menu command (I have to get the program to return to the main menu), only the very first result in the text file is displayed (in this case that being Ted History Easy 4 points Grade : B), but as soon as I get rid of the lines of code saying return menu(), all the results for the username that was input are displayed. How can I get the code to both display all the results and to return to the main menu ?

Comment: Can you post the full code please?

Comment: Your return statement ends the loop on the first iteration. Don't indent it

Comment: `return` in programming does not exactly mean "go to somewhere else", it means to "give back that variable to the calling function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove your `return` statement from the loop if you want to print more than one result, i.e.:

```
def results():
   found = False
   username = input("Enter username :")
   with open("scorefile.txt","r") as f:
       for line in f:
           if username in line:
               print (line)
               found = True
       if not found:
           print("No such user")
   menu()  # call your menu() function in the end
```

You also don't need to `return menu()` unless you expect whatever `menu()` returns to be returned by your `results()` function.

Another problem you will notice with your code is when somebody enters `points` as a username. You might want to form your condition as: `if line.startswith(username): ...`